# Swift: Error When Removing Status Bar

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, xcode7-beta6

I am trying to remove the status bar from my UIViewController. I went into the info.plist and changed the `View controller-based status bar appearance` to `NO` and in my AppDelegate.swift I implemented the following:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    application.statusBarHidden = true
    return true
}
```

How come when I run my app, I get the following error's in the console. I am running Xcode Version 7.0 beta 6 (7A192o):

> `<Error>`: CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>
> `<Error>`: CGContextTranslateCTM: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.
>
> `<Error>`: CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.

It is important to note that the status bar is removed from the view. I just get this error whenever I run the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with iOS 9. You can safely ignore this error.

(https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/13683)

Comment: The issue is related to Xcode 7, not iOS 9..